# Bound on the difference of integrals with respect to different measures?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any method to bound $\left| \int f\,du - \int f\,dv \right|=\left| \int f\, (du-dv) \right|$? If we know $\int g\, du-\int g\, dv$ is close for some other function $g$, what can we do? I'm wondering if there are any common techniques or tricks.

Comment: Is there a change of variables formula between $du$ and $dv$ you can use?

Comment: Nope. Here, $du$ is a true measure and $dv$ is the empirical measure, so I should've written this more like $Pf-P_n f$ vs $Pg-P_n g$.

Comment: If you are familar with signed measures and total variation then you can use: $|\int fdu-\int fdv| \leq \int |f|d|u-v|$.